# Azure B2C telemetry into application insights not working on production

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-application-insights, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Around a week ago our team deployed an update on the policies in production by adapting the app insights integration config to conform with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-application-insights-in-production) on how it should be in production environments. i.e. set `DeploymentMode` and `DeveloperMode` to `false`. So we did it.

However, since then the app insights instance has not been receiving any data.

Any clues? Seems it has happened before [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2683/can-we-configure-application-insights-for-adb2c-cu.html).

Please consider taking a look at our relevant files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="{Settings:Tenant}" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_AccountLink_SUSI" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://{Settings:Tenant}/B2C_1A_AccountLink_SUSI" 
  TenantObjectId=""
  DeploymentMode="Production"
  UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">
  <!--WARNING: Do not set the DeploymentMode to Development in production environments. -->
```

```
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="AccountLinkSignUpOrSignIn" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="{Settings:ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey}" DeveloperMode="false" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Comment: On that doc page it says: "Use the following configuration in production environments and no logs will be sent to your application insights." JourneyInsights is kinda dangerous to enable in production as it logs everything in the policies, including all user inputs.

Comment: Geez, you are right! I thought that only irrelevant logs would not be sent. first, it states that prod config implies: "ignoring messages that are unimportant." and in the next sentence: "no logs will be sent". oddly confused:sweatsmile:

Comment: Would then the alternative be Azure Monitoring as suggested here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor

Comment: You can still use log analytics.

Comment: I hit the same issue. It's surprising that this doesn't log ANY logs whatsoever. Eg. a customer is currently getting an error logging in, and we have no way of knowing why.